# What is the best technique to make the image 28x28 in Machine Learning?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-resizing

I am training a Machine Learning classifier and with all the tutorials I have seen so far, the size of the image which is widely used in these kind of classification task in 28*28(mnist) or 32*32(cifar-10).

With my dataset what I am having is 100*150(say). I used OpenCV to resize the images to 28*28 (with the interpolation technique INTER_AREA). If I resize this image directly what I get is the different shape image than the original image.

For example if my original image is rectangle, I would get a square on resizing to 28*28.

[image]  [image]

To maintain the shape(aspect ratio) what I did was, I created a square canvas with maximumum size(here 150*150) with zeros around the corner pasted my original(100*150) image there and then I resized the image to 28*28. By this way I maintained the shape as it is.

**My question is that
whether anyone faced this same issue and what is the best technique that can be followed to make the image of size 28*28 ?? Or my way of doing is correct?**

Comment: Depends on the content of the image?

Comment: The other option is to crop it to have the same aspect ratio

Comment: @moooeeeep : How content matters, my data fills across the image.

Comment: @api55 : could you please elaborate. while cropping we would need to eliminate few parts of the image. How does it help me? I want to have the rectangle shape maintained in 28*28 also

Comment: It depends on the image, in some cases you can crop part of the data, and still get a lot of important data in the image. However, if you have quite important data on the borders, then a bar or extra padding info is added to the image, but note that this will also be used as information.... Also it depends what you want to achieve, if you want to differentiate between rectangles and squares.... well you need the whole data, if it is faces it may not be required to have the complete face, to be able to detect one (e.g. partial occlusion)

Comment: When you apply the same transformation to the test data as to the training data, your classification results might not be influenced by a distorted aspect ratio after all.

Comment: What if I told you that you can design your own network and use your original images, without resizing? You don't have to standarize at 32x32 or 28x28.

Comment: So can the input image be of any shape say 145*105 @Matias Valdenegro. Do you mean to say It doesnt has to be a square shape

Comment: @api55 I want to differentiate between rectangles and squares.... so as you said I need the whole data. Do you suggest any technique to convert the images to a standard size

Comment: perhaps something like mogrify, and if the background is always white, fill the extra padding (equal in both sides) with white until is full. also try to get samples in different orientations to get a more complete training set

Comment: @Karthik Precisely, it can be any shape as you are training a network from scratch.